# Java: ObjectMapper changes value/structure of Pojo after request/response

Tags: java, spring, jackson, objectmapper

I can see before the conversion of the response to my DTO it looks like this:

```json
{
    "name": "HalloweenBundle2021",
    "pricing":
    {
        "VirtualCurrencyDto(physicalCurrency=EUR, coinId=null)":
        {
            "amount": 8.99,
            "discountAmount": 0
        },
        "VirtualCurrencyDto(physicalCurrency=USD, coinId=null)":
        {
            "amount": 9.99,
            "discountAmount": 0
        }
    }
}
```

which is correct.

However, after the response/actual conversion, both of the `physicalCurrency` fields are null, whereas the `coinId` fields get full map values:

```json
{
    "name": "HalloweenBundle2021",
    "pricing":
    {
        "VirtualCurrencyDto(physicalCurrency=null, coinId=VirtualCurrencyDto(physicalCurrency=EUR, coinId=null))":
        {
            "amount": 8.99,
            "discountAmount": 0
        },
        "VirtualCurrencyDto(physicalCurrency=null, coinId=VirtualCurrencyDto(physicalCurrency=USD, coinId=null))":
        {
            "amount": 9.99,
            "discountAmount": 0
        }
    }
}
```

What is going on exactly?

My Pojo for the response is:

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class FooDto implements Serializable {
  private String name;
  private Map<VirtualCurrencyDto, PriceDto> pricing = new LinkedHashMap<>();
}
```

and the pojo in with the issue is:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class VirtualCurrencyDto implements Serializable {

  // both of these fields should not be present, only one or the other
  private DTOCurrency physicalCurrency; // an external enum
  private String coinId;

  public VirtualCurrencyDto(DTOCurrency physicalCurrency) {
    this.physicalCurrency = physicalCurrency;
  }

  public VirtualCurrencyDto(String coinId) {
    this.coinId = coinId;
  }
}
```

my objectMapper bean

```
  @Bean
  public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper()
        .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
        .registerModule(new JsonNullableModule());
  }
```

And the response is being fetched via `MockMvc`

```
  public FooDto getFooDto(String name) throws Exception {
    MvcResult result =
        mockMvc.perform(
                get("/foo/" + name))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();

    return objectMapper.readValue(
        result.getResponse().getContentAsString(), // this part is fine, when I look at the string value
        FooDto.class); // issue here, upon conversion
      }
```

I should note that the same is true when making the request, e.g. before the request reaches my controller for a `PUT`, the data looks fine, but upon receiving it in the controller, the data is screwed like above (the response from `GET`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the issue exists because you have a complex object as the key of your `pricing` Map. Maps in JSON are represented by a simple `String` as key and the value could be a complex object. This means that Jackson has to find a way to serialize your complex `VirtualCurrencyDto` object into a simple `String`. The only way to do this is via the `toString()` method, which is why you see `"VirtualCurrencyDto(physicalCurrency=null, coinId=VirtualCurrencyDto(physicalCurrency=EUR, coinId=null))"`. This is wrong *per se*, because you should use simple objects that have a simple `String` representation as keys in JSON maps. But next, we will see why you are getting such weird behavior.

Jackson tries to deserialize `"VirtualCurrencyDto(physicalCurrency=null, coinId=VirtualCurrencyDto(physicalCurrency=EUR, coinId=null))"` into a `VirtualCurrencyDto` object. Since it contains only a single `String` property my guess is that it creates an instance of `VirtualCurrencyDto` with `"VirtualCurrencyDto(physicalCurrency=null, coinId=VirtualCurrencyDto(physicalCurrency=EUR, coinId=null))"` as the value for `coinId`, the only `String` property in `VirtualCurrencyDto`, hence the behaviour you are experiencing.

You have two options here:

1. You review your model classes so that you use a simple object as the key of `pricing` Map. `DTOCurrency` would be a good candidate for example.
2. You create a custom deserializer for `VirtualCurrencyDto` that is able to parse the `String` `"VirtualCurrencyDto(physicalCurrency=null, coinId=VirtualCurrencyDto(physicalCurrency=EUR, coinId=null))"` and create an instance of the class. For this you will need to extend `StdDeserializer` and then register it in your `ObjectMapper`. Something similar to the following:

```java
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule()
        .addDeserializer(VirtualCurrencyDto.class, new VirtualCurrencyDtoDeserializer());

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(module);
```

I would go with the first one.